# how to treat acct = 'labor ot' and acct = 'labor' as the same when grouping the column acct

Tags: sql, sql-server

below is my query:

```
select fiscalno, acct, data1, employee, project, pjt_entity,
 SUM(units) as units, SUM(amount) as amount, tr_id03, tr_id05, vendor_num
from dbo.PJTran
group by fiscalno, acct, data1, employee, project, pjt_entity, tr_id03, tr_id05, vendor_num
order by fiscalno, acct, employee
```

only problem is that when acct is entered in the database it goes in as `labor` or `labor OT` (overtime) if the employee entered the hours as overtime.  As a result the query treats them as separate when grouping the column together as it should. However, I want to be able to group both labor OT and labor together as the same field.

Any help would be great.

Comment: put `CASE` on acct column. Something like `CASE WHEN acct = 'labor ot' THEN 'labot' ELSE acct END as acct`. Maybe should put same to Group By

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I did try and use a CASE statement before but must have had the syntax incorrect because it wasn't working. But this one works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
fiscalno, CASE WHEN acct='labor ot' then 'labor'else acct end as 'acct', data1, employee, project, pjt_entity, SUM(units) as units, SUM(amount) as amount, tr_id03, tr_id05, vendor_num
from dbo.PJTran 
group by fiscalno, CASE WHEN acct='labor ot' then 'labor'else acct end, data1, employee, project, pjt_entity, tr_id03, tr_id05, vendor_num
order by fiscalno, acct, employee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CASE function as Darka suggested. Here's a modified version of the query. It uses the CASE function on acct values. A CTE is used to avoid the repetition of the CASE statement in the SELECT and the GROUP BY statements.

```
WITH UPDATED_ACCT AS
(
  SELECT
  fiscalno, (CASE WHEN acct = 'labor ot' THEN 'labor' ELSE acct END) acct, data1, employee, project, pjt_entity, units, amount, tr_id03, tr_id05, vendor_num
  FROM DBO.PJTRAN
)
SELECT 
  FISCALNO, ACCT, DATA1, EMPLOYEE, PROJECT, PJT_ENTITY, SUM(UNITS) AS UNITS, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, TR_ID03, TR_ID05, VENDOR_NUM
FROM UPDATED_ACCT
GROUP BY fiscalno, acct, data1, employee, project, pjt_entity, tr_id03, tr_id05, vendor_num
ORDER BY FISCALNO, ACCT, EMPLOYEE  ;
```

**References**:

[Using CASE statement within GROUP BY on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17a6c4f4-3a44-4d72-89e4-37c3ab9df532/using-case-statement-within-group-by)